# Redirect to subsite when authenticating using FBA

Tags: forms-authentication, custom-login-page

Using SharePoing 2010.  I have configured a Claims Based Authentication web application allowing Windows Authentication (NTLM) and FBA.  All is good there.  I am able to login using my Windows credentials and FBA credentials.  When I login using FBA credentials I would like to be redirected to a specific site collection.  Where could I include this custom code or logic to handle the redirect?  I created a custom Login page so that I could apply my own branding.  Would the redirect logic be included in the custom login.aspx code behind?  Am I able to modify the authenticate.aspx page?  Examples are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user arrives on the login page, there should be a query string parameter `Source`. Once you know the user is using FBA, you can modify this parameter from your custom login page. SharePoint should then send the user back to where you want.